# What exactly is a 'Camera Preview' object in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, resolution, preview

I've to work with camera for the first time on the Android platform. My goal is to be able to snap an image with an optimum resolution and then transfer it over the network with the least level of compression.

The function "`getSupportedPictureSizes`" gives me the resolutions supported by the camera. But do I apply my desired resolution on the preview object (android.view.SurfaceView) or on the camera parameter object (android.hardware.Camera.Parameters)?

Apologies in advance if the question doesn't make sense but I'm confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But do I apply my desired resolution on the preview object (android.view.SurfaceView) or on the camera parameter object (android.hardware.Camera.Parameters)?

`getSupportedPictureSizes()` is for pictures. You update the `Camera.Parameters` via `setPictureSize()` to indicate what `Camera.Size` you want for the actual picture taken via `takePicture()`.

`getSupportedPreviewSizes()` is for preview frames. You update the `Camera.Parameters` via `setPreviewSize()` to indicate what `Camera.Size` you want for the preview frames. You probably also want to set up your `Surface` to be the same size, or at least the same aspect ratio, so the image does not get stretched or squished.

And, FWIW, you may find [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) easier to use than the native `Camera` API.